# Can I choose my universal set to be convenient for the given problem?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm attempting to prove this fact from Abbot's Understanding Analysis

[image]

Now what I would like to do is assume that $a + t \not\in \mathbb{I}$ or $at \not\in \mathbb{I}$ with the assumption that my universal set $U$ is $\mathbb{R}$, so $a + t \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $at \in \mathbb{Q}$ because $\mathbb{I}^C = \mathbb{Q}$ and then derive a contradiction.

This would work just fine if I assume that $\mathbb{R}$ is my universal set. But there's the obvious possibility of choosing $U = \mathbb{C}$, which would break my argument. Is doing this reasonable?

Comment: Yes, it is: in this context it is clear that we’re talking about real numbers, since both $a+t$ and $at$ are necessarily real. That is, if, for instance, $a+t\notin\Bbb I$, then it must be in $\Bbb Q$, since it’s in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with a universal set. $\mathbb I$ is unambiguously just $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$.

So since $\mathbb R$ is a field, both $a+t$ and $at$ are in $\mathbb R$. You need to show they are, in fact, both in $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$.